# GNU 4.8.1 Any C++ compile crashes after systemupdate

Tags: c++, gnu, xubuntu, g++4.8

Lately I've updated my OS to Xubuntu 13.10. Now any C++ compile using GNU 4.8.1 compiler crashes with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've removed anything from source and use only an empty main function:

```
#if defined(linux) || defined(__linux)
int main()
{

   return 0;
}
#endif
```

The failure exist. I tried Xubuntu 13.10 32bit and 64bit version. Failure exist on both.
GDB reports:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6c33f77 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Edit:

Meanwhile I figured out that the problem is based on my singleton implementation. This implementation works successfully with MinGW-64 in handshake with GCC 4.8 and with Xubuntu 13.04:

```
namespace binrev{
namespace brCore{

template <typename T>
class DLL_EXPORT brSingleton
{
   public:
   static T& getInstance()
   {
  std::call_once(m_once, safe_create);   
      return *m_instance;        
   }

   protected:
   brSingleton(const std::string& name)
   : m_name(name)
   {}

   static void safe_create() {
  brSingleton::m_instance.reset(new T());
   }

   brSingleton(const brSingleton& rs) = delete;
   brSingleton& operator = (const brSingleton& rs) = delete;

   virtual ~brSingleton(){}

protected:
   static std::unique_ptr<T> m_instance;
   static std::once_flag m_once;         
   std::string m_name;
};
template<typename T> 
std::once_flag brSingleton<T>::m_once;
}// ns-brCore
}// ns-binrev
```

If I call getInstance at concrete singleton implementation, the crash occurs on std::call_once function call.

I'm running out of ideas. Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you install GCC 4.8.1?  Did you compile it yourself, or was it an Xubuntu package?  If you compiled it yourself, then you should consider recompiling from scratch.  If it was an Xubuntu package, then you should seek out the Xubuntu support forums.

Comment: I use the xubuntu install. Meanwhile I've figured out that there must be a source problem, the pure main function works now.

Comment: Not a programming problem but a distribution/packaging problem, as such it is off topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved after installing xubuntu 13.10 64bit a fourth time. I think there was some packing corruption as mentioned by syam during installation.